# SignalR.Client/Azure Service Bus MessageId issue

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, signalr, azureservicebus

Just hooked SignalR.WindowsAzureServiceBus to my web project and it appears to cause a problem in the SignalR.Client library. I get the following error when I send a message:

```
Format Exception: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

So I downloaded the source and debugged and this is the offending line of code

```
connection.MessageId = result["MessageId"].Value<long>();

@SignalR.Client.Transports.HttpBasedTransport.ProcessResponse(...)
[SignalR.Client.Silverlight5]
```

It results from trying to parse the following JSON pair's value to a long:

```
"MessageId": "3wIAASMAAAA%3D"
```

It appears that with Service Bus enabled, the MessageId is not a long, as "3wIAASMAAAA%3D" is clearly not parsable to a long.

I see the topics are created in the Azure management portal, so I know it's connecting to the Service Bus just fine.

Did I do something silly or do I need to patch it for a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bug. I've opened an issue on github. https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/475

Comment: Thanks David. For future reference, is there a process for submitting something like this; like on the project site on github or something?

Comment: Yep, you just file a issue on github. I just fixed it btw.

Comment: Oh snap! You're awesome... so's this product. I'll pull it down. Thanks.